# $A^{\ast}$ compact $\Rightarrow A$ compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I read that if $A:E\to E$ is a bounded linear operator where $E$ is a Banach space and $A^{\ast}$ is a [compact operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator), then $A$ is a compact operator.

I know that the converse is true ([th. 4 here](http://librarum.org/book/10022/127)), but I cannot prove the lemma above. I have tried to apply Arzelà's theorem, similarly to how it is done in the quoted th. 4, but I cannot get anything...

Thank you so much for any help!!!

Comment: Hint: $A^{\ast\ast}$ is compact. What is the relation between $A$ and $A^{\ast\ast}$ with respect to the canonical embedding $E\hookrightarrow E^{\ast\ast}$?

Comment: Thank you so much! $E\hookrightarrow E^{\ast\ast}$, $x\mapsto (-,x)$ is an isometry, but I don't see how we can relate it to $A^{\ast}:f\mapsto f\circ A$...

Comment: See also http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1298

Comment: @TomekKania Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $J\colon E\hookrightarrow E^{\ast\ast}$ be the canonical embedding. For $x\in E$ and $\lambda \in E^\ast$, we have

$$A^{\ast\ast}(Jx)(\lambda) = (Jx \circ A^\ast)(\lambda) = Jx(A^\ast\lambda) = (A^\ast\lambda)(x) = (\lambda\circ A)(x) = \lambda(Ax) = J(Ax)(\lambda),$$

so $A^{\ast\ast}\circ J = J\circ A$. Looking at the commutative diagram

$$\begin{matrix}\;\;\; E & \xrightarrow{A} &\mspace{-11mu} E\\
J\downarrow & & \downarrow J \\
\;\;\;\;E^{\ast\ast} & \xrightarrow[A^{\ast\ast}]{} & \mspace{-3mu} E^{\ast\ast}
\end{matrix}$$

and keeping in mind that $J(E)$ is a closed subspace of $E^{\ast\ast}$, and of course the compactness of $A^{\ast\ast}$, can you see that there is a compact subset $K$ of $E$ such that $A(B_E) \subset K$, where $B_X$ denotes the (closed) unit ball of the space $X$?

Comment: $\infty$ thanks!!! I've proven to myself that $J(E)$ is close if $E$ is complete: am I right?

Comment: Yes. $E^{\ast\ast}$ is always a Banach space (I'm only considering normed spaces now), so $J(E)$ is closed if and only if $J(E)$ is complete. Since $J$ is an isometry, $J(E)$ is complete if and only if $E$ is.

Comment: Very kind. Thank you a lot again!!!